# I'm not able to scrape data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape data from the website. Here's my code

```
import scrapy


class ShopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shop'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html?sort_by=bestsellers']
    start_urls = ['http://https://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html?sort_by=bestsellers/']
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'tmp/shop.csv'
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        titles = response.css('img::attr(title)').extract()
        images = response.css('img::attr(data-img)').extract()
        prices = response.css('.p_price::text').extract()
        discounts = response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()

        for item in zip(titles, prices, images, discounts):
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'price': item[1],
                'image_urls': [item[2]],  # Set's the url for scrapy to download images
                'discount': item[3]
        }

        yield scraped_info
```

Please check where I'm doing wrong?
Also, I want to scrape all the data while I'm scrolling. So it should take all the data till we are scrolling? So how do I go about it?

Comment: do you call your `parse()` function ever ?

Comment: What's the problem? Please be clear.

Comment: Suppose I just want the title so I'm trying to run this in a shell but It's showing list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You have problems with:

1. incorrect `allowed_domain` (only domain needed);
2. broken `start_urls` (http twice and slash in the end);
3. wrong intends for yielding item in `parse` function.

Check fixed code here:

```
import scrapy

class ShopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shop'
    allowed_domains = ['shopclues.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html?sort_by=bestsellers']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.css('img::attr(title)').extract()
        images = response.css('img::attr(data-img)').extract()
        prices = response.css('.p_price::text').extract()
        discounts = response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()

        for item in zip(titles, prices, images, discounts):
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'price': item[1],
                'image_urls': [item[2]],  # Set's the url for scrapy to download images
                'discount': item[3]
            }

            yield scraped_info
```

Comment: Thanks. So now I want to scrape the data while I'm scrolling. Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: If you will check what happens in developer tools, while you scrolling, you will see links kinda `https://www.shopclues.com/ajaxCall/moreProducts?catId=1431&filters=&pageType=c&start=72&columns=4&fl_cal=1&page=4&url_link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shopclues.com%2Fmobiles-smartphones&DM_TEXT=&sc_z=4444`. So make iterative requests and get all the data, changing `page` and `start` params.

Comment: I'm looking for a different solution.

Comment: Ok, use Splash + Lua scripts; use Selenium.

Comment: I don't have much idea about this. Can you share some link?